# Ubuntu Touch - Today scope freezing

Tags: ubuntu-touch, m10

Over the last few weeks I have noticed that my Today Scope is taking around 30 - 50 seconds to refresh on my M10 tablet, when I pull the screen down to trigger the refresh. This does not happen on my wife's tablet though, which has far fewer apps installed on it.

Has anyone had this happen to them and/or do you know how I can resolve this? When the refresh freeze is taking place, I am unable to swipe to any other scopes.

i have the latest version of Touch running on both tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Since it does not happen on your wifes device with fewer apps installed, i would just assume it's an issue of insufficient memory. Remember that the M10 does not feature particularly beefy hardware.

The only fix i can imagine is activating less scopes. Use only those you really need and kill apps while you're not using them. I know, this does not really help you (my answer basically is "In order to use your device, don't use it", but I don't see another way.

Maybe you can file a bug report and ask the devs to optimize the scope: https://bugs.launchpad.net/today-scope

Comment: Noit had any issues on mine, but there again I only use it for the basics and do not have that many apps loaded. I came to Ubuntu Touch with the though that I would only use what I needed and not download all the apps going for the sake of it, like I did with my android.